# javascript pass

Tags: javascript, python, exception

Is there something along the lines of python 'pass' in javascript?

I want to do the javascript equivalent of:

```
try:
  # Something that throws exception
catch:
  pass
```

Comment: Empty braces aren't doing the trick? By the way, silently eating exceptions is almost always the wrong thing to do.

Comment: [Try/Catch reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch)

Comment: To Adam's point, I have a new answer to this old question that adjusts for Python's nuanced error handling below here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/28288015/541136

Answer (score 52, accepted):

[`pass` is a no-op in Python.](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/pass.html) You need it for empty blocks because

```
try:
    # Something that throws exception
catch:

# continue other stuff
```

[is a syntax error](http://ideone.com/W13ic). In JavaScript you can just use an empty `catch` block.

```
try {
    // Something that throws exception
}
catch (e) {}
```

Comment: `eslint` complains about this.

Comment: @naught101 Well yeah, of course it does. Linters are pretty much built to tell us about potentially dangerous things like this. I generally put a comment in the block explaining why I'm not handling the error, which gets rid of the eslint warning. Or you could change rule 'no-empty' to 'off'

Comment: add a comment on catch block and eslint will be happy! catch (e) { /* empty */ }

Answer (score 38):

There is, and here it is:

That's right, nothing at all:

```
try {
    somethingThatThrowsAnException();
} catch (e) {
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> I want to do the javascript equivalent of:
>
> ```
> try:
>   # Something that throws exception
> catch:
>   pass
> ```

Python doesn't have try/catch. It has try/except. So replacing `catch` with `except`, we would have this:

```
try {
  //     throw any exception
} catch(err) {}
```

The empty code block after the catch is equivalent to Python's `pass`.

**Best Practices**

However, one might interpret this question a little differently. Suppose you want to adopt the same semantics as a Python try/except block. Python's exception handling is a little more nuanced, and lets you specify what errors to catch.

In fact, it is considered a best practice to only catch specific error types.

So a best practice version for Python would be, since you want to only catch exceptions you are prepared to handle, and avoid hiding bugs:

```
try:
    raise TypeError
except TypeError as err:
    pass
```

You should probably subclass the appropriate error type, standard Javascript doesn't have a very rich exception hierarchy. I chose `TypeError` because it has the same spelling and similar semantics to Python's `TypeError`.

To follow the same semantics for this in Javascript, we first [have to catch all errors](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-12.14), and so we need control flow that adjusts for that. So we need to determine if the error is not the type of error we want to `pass` with an if condition. The lack of else control flow is what silences the `TypeError`. And with this code, in theory, all other types of errors should bubble up to the surface and be fixed, or at least be identified for additional error handling:

```
try {                                 // try:
  throw TypeError()                   //     raise ValueError
} catch(err) {                        // # this code block same behavior as
  if (!(err instanceof TypeError)) {  // except ValueError as err:
    throw err                         //     pass
  } 
}
```

Comments welcome!